# Using open() and read() in C to check a file

Tags: c, windows, file

I am new to C, for a project I need to read a file and find how many 'upgrades', 'installs' and 'removes' there are in a txt file with Pacman package manager logs, which I checked using an open() call (still wondering what the modes are for though).

This is my code:

```
  char *file;
  int fd;
  size_t size = 1000;
  int characters;
  char buffer[size];
  int upgraded, removed, installed;
  upgraded = removed = installed = 0;

  file = logFile;

  fd = open(file, O_RDONLY, 0600);

  if(fd == -1){
        printf("Unreadable");
        exit(1);
  }

  characters = read(fd, buffer, size);

  for(;;)
  {
        //printf("\n\nUff\n\n");
        characters = read(fd, buffer, size);

        if(characters == -1){
              printf("Error");
              exit(1);
              break;
        }

        if(characters == 0) break;

        if(strstr(buffer, "upgraded") != NULL) {
              upgraded++;
        }
        if(strstr(buffer, "installed") != NULL) {
              installed++;
        }
        if(strstr(buffer, "removed") != NULL) {
              removed++;
        }

        printf("%s", buffer);
  }

  printf("\n\n%d, %d, %d \n\n", installed, removed, upgraded);

  if(close(fd) == -1){
        printf("Unreadable");
        exit(1);
  }
```

For some reason, the same 20 lines repeat over and over when printing the buffer on the terminal like this:

```
1-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded fuse-common (3.6.2-1 -> 3.6.2-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded fuse2 (2.9.9-1 -> 2.9.9-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded gettext (0.20.1-1 -> 0.20.1-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded libxfont2 (2.0.3-1 -> 2.0.4-1)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded shared-mime-info (1.12-1 -> 1.13.1-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded xorg-xkbcomp (1.4.2-1 -> 1.4.2+7+g29fda8e-1)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running '30-systemd-udev-reload.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running '30-systemd-update.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running 'texinfo-install.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running 'update-mime-database.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman --color auto -U --noconfirm /tmp/yaourt-tmp-onmunoz/PKGDEST.QXQ/mock-core-configs-31.3-1.1-any.pkg.tar.xz'
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction started
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded mock-core-configs (31.2-1.1 -> 3(31.2-1.1 -> 3#ÇvÇv╗÷l)Ó@

1.3-1.1)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction completedd2-1 -> 3.6.2-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded fuse2 (2.9.9-1 -> 2.9.9-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded gettext (0.20.1-1 -> 0.20.1-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded libxfont2 (2.0.3-1 -> 2.0.4-1)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded shared-mime-info (1.12-1 -> 1.13.1-2)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded xorg-xkbcomp (1.4.2-1 -> 1.4.2+7+g29fda8e-1)
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running '30-systemd-udev-reload.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running '30-systemd-update.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running 'texinfo-install.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] running 'update-mime-database.hook'...
[2019-09-17 12:39] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman --color auto -U --noconfirm /tmp/yaourt-tmp-onmunoz/PKGDEST.QXQ/mock-core-configs-31.3-1.1-any.pkg.tar.xz'
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction started
[2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] upgraded mock-core-configs (31.2-1.1 -> 3(31.2-1.1 -> 3#ÇvÇv╗÷l)Ó@


92, 8, 111

Report is generated at: [packages_report.txt]
```

And I cannot find the reason (is it the way I use the read() or the pointers?) for the read() function to just read the same lines instead of reading the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you are interpreting the data. It seems that you are assuming that each `read` call is reading exactly one line of the file. That is not the case. `read` will read up to the number of bytes you specify in the `count` parameter.

So in your case the sequence of your code is roughly as follows. I need to say roughly as you have not given your exact log file so I need to guess the contents (specifically the size of the contents).

1. Outside the loop: `characters = read(fd, buffer, size);`. That will read 1000 bytes into the `buffer`.
2. First time `read` inside the loop. That will read the next 1000 bytes into the buffer.
3. First time `printf` inside the loop. That will print the previously read 1000 bytes.
4. Second time `read` inside the loop. That will attempt to read the next 1000 bytes. However, there isn't 1000 bytes left (I'm guessing here) so only the start of the buffer is overwritten.
5. Second time `printf` inside the loop. Now the last part of the file read in step 4 is shown first and then the remaining part of the read in step 2 is shown.

You can somewhat see this in that the last repeated block's first line is:

```
2019-09-17 12:39] [ALPM] transaction completedd2-1 -> 3.6.2-2)
```

We can see that `transaction completed` is actually the last line of the log file (my guess). And then there is some extra output from the previous `read`.

The way to fix this? Use `fgets` to read one line at a time.